# Skewness of the sum of dependent variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, skewness, moments, cumulants

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are both time series of observations.  The two series are not independent. I want to find the skewness, kurtosis, hyper-skewness and hyper-kurtosis of $X+Y$ and $X-Y$.

I have no information about the distribution of $X$ and $Y$, except that $X,Y > 0$ and it is reasonable to assume they have exponential tails and finite variance.

Just to confirm this is not in relation to coursework or examination question!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "higher-order" statistics.  Cumulants, after all, are functions of (positive integral) moments of *all* orders.  In what sense do you "have" variables that enables you to "estimate" moments of their sum or difference?  Are you asking about theoretical distributions or are you asking about data?

Comment: Hope the edits clarify my question

Comment: Since these are time series, there may be a sharp difference between (a) moments of hypothesized marginal distributions and (b) moments of the data themselves.  For the latter, nothing prevents you from computing the moments directly from the $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ data. For the former, what is your model for these time series processes?